# JSON data incomplete

Tags: c#, json, api, xamarin, json.net

I and two other students are making a multiplatform sportapp with Xamarin.
The app can gather data while training and the user can see back trainings and
measurements (last one is done by sport physicians).

We use an API to get stuff from the online database.
Getting the list of trainings for the current user works fine.
When getting a list of measurements however, the JSON data seems incomplete.

See the image below for the database structure of the measurements. Each measurement has some global data saved in the "Metingen". The results of the measurements are saved in the table "Resultaten". Every row of a results (e.g. Weight, BMI ect.) has it's own row in the "Resultaten" table. Each result of a measurement has a TypeID. This is used to get the data of the type of measurement from the "Types" table (e.g. name="Weight", unit="kg" etc.).

What we are currently missing in the JSON data is the name of a measurementdetail (e.g. "Weight" or "BMI" from the "Types" table).
We get a correct TypeID back in the JSON data but not always the data from the table (one measurement of the 3 we try to get is totally complete). Instead we get Type:{ "$ref: 1}

Thanks in advance!

**Database diagram for measurements**
[image: Database diagram for measurements]

**JSON for one measurement result (one row)**
[image: JSON for one measurement result (one row)]

Method that does the api call:

```
    private void getMeasurementsFromDB()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new ApiRequest()
            .SetLogin(UserRepository.Instance().login)
            .Get("api/meting");

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var JSON = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var jsonarray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSON.Result);

            JArray measurements = JArray.FromObject(jsonarray);
            foreach (JObject measurement in measurements)
            {
                if (!MeasurementRepository.Instance().measurementExistsLocally((int)measurement["ID"]))
                {
                    int measurementId = (int)measurement["ID"];
                    DateTime date = (DateTime)measurement["Datum"];
                    string userId = (string)measurement["Deelnemer"]["Login"];
                    string conclusion = (string)measurement["Conclusie"];
                    int state = (int)measurement["Status"];
                    LocalMeasurementModel tempMeasurement = new LocalMeasurementModel(measurementId, date, userId, conclusion, state);
                    MeasurementRepository.Instance().saveMeasurementModel(tempMeasurement);

                    JArray locationInfos = (JArray)measurement["Resultaten"];
                    foreach (JObject result in locationInfos)
                    {
                        LocalMeasurementDetailModel localResults = new LocalMeasurementDetailModel();
                        localResults.measurementId = (int)measurement["ID"];
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)result["WaardeString"]))
                        {
                            localResults.value = (string)result["WaardeString"];
                        }
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)result["WaardeFloat"]))
                        {
                            localResults.value = (string)result["WaardeFloat"];
                        }
                        localResults.unit = (string)result["Type"]["Eenheid"];
                        localResults.name = (string)result["Type"]["Naam"];
                        MeasurementRepository.Instance().saveMeasurementDetailModel(localResults);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
        MeasurementRepository.Instance().busy = false;
        loadMeasurements();
    }
```

The API uses entity framework.
API function that receives the call:

```
    [IsalaAuthorize(Rechten =
        "meting_eigen_ophalen, " +
        "meting_alle_ophalen")]
    [GET("api/meting")]
    public IEnumerable<Meting> GetMetingen()
    {
        var principal = HttpContext.Current.User;

        if (principal.IsInRole("meting_alle_ophalen"))
        {
            Log.Info("[Metingen] Alle metingen worden opgehaald.");
            return Metingen.GetAll();
        }
        Log.Info("[Metingen] Alle metingen van gebruiker '" + principal.Identity.Name + " worden opgehaald.");
        return Metingen.GetAllByGebruiker(principal.Identity.Name);
    }
```

API method to get data from database

```
    public IEnumerable<Meting> GetAllByGebruiker(string id)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        IEnumerable<Meting> metingen = db.Metingen
             .Include("Deelnemer")
             .Include(c => c.Resultaten)
             .Include("Resultaten.Type")
             .Where(m => m.Deelnemer.Login.Contains(id))
             .OrderByDescending(x => x.Datum);

        foreach (Meting meting in metingen)
        {
            meting.Resultaten = meting.Resultaten
                .Where(r => r.Revisie == meting.Resultaten.Where(rm => rm.TypeID == r.TypeID)
                    .Max(rm => rm.Revisie))
                .ToList();
        }
        return metingen;
    }
```

Comment: Can it be that your web service is not communicated all the information? As my Dutch is not as pronounced, here I come a little confused with the allocation of values. ;)

Have you access to WebService source? And could post an example?

Comment: I added the code from the API we use. Since the JSON is incomplete we suspect something isn't going right in the API

Comment: The last thing to suspect when something isn't working is the framework code. Web API returns exactly what you return from the action method. Just introduce an intermediate variable `var allMeasurements = Metingen.GetAll(); return allMeasurements;` and inspect its contents.

Comment: The result `"Type" : { "$ref" : "1" }` indicates you have a circular reference in your JSON (probably also in your business model). From the looks of it you have a class `Resultaat` which holds an reference to a `Type` object. Does your `Type` object also holds a reference back to a list of `Resultaat` objects?

Could you maybe include the code for the `Resultaat` and the `Type` classes?

Comment: You can use Runscope: https://www.runscope.com/ or Fiddler: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler to inspect your request and response. I have used both before to track down similar issues.